Fission reactions with small nuclei
Why are there no fission reactions which produce small nuclei as a result such as a deuteron or tritium?

Fission reactions that sometimes produce light particles, are known as ternary fission. Ternary fission accounts for between 0.2 and 0.4% of all fission reactions. And of the ternary fissions, about 90% of the fission products are helium-4 nuclei and 7% are hydrogen-3 nuclei, aka triton.
